# Multiple objects in a callback

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm using [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) to communicate with a webservice. The server returns a response JSON which contains `success` (a boolean), and if `success` is false, the response also contains a `message` (String). But, if `success` is true, the response will contain the request result, eg a List<> of users or a single user or something else, depending on the request.

```
public class User {
    public String fullname,phone;
}
```

The retrofit API:

```
public interface DemoAPI {

@GET("/users/{id}")
void getUserInformation(@Path("id") int userID, Callback<User> callback);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/login")
void login(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password,Callback<??> callback);
}
```

The question is, what to do if I want to, for example, log a user in and return his `User` information? The callback should then include both the user object and the `success` + `message` values (message if needed), but I can't put those inside a single `User` since some requests return a `List<User>`.

Comment: Are you saying that `/login` will return multiple users sometimes? That would seem to be a rather odd implementation of a login API.

Comment: No, /login always returns the specific logged in user's information. I was saying that there are other requests (not in the code posted here) the can return multiple users

Comment: Then I fail to see what your problem is. You create a Java class that models the `/login` response (boolean + user + message) and use that with your `login()` method and the `Callback`. Your `login()` method has nothing to do with any other REST requests you may be making, so the fact that `/foo` might return a list of users wouldn't seem to be relevant for your implementation of the `/login` response handling.

Comment: You're totally right, I don't know why I complicated myself in a problem that doesn't even exist, I guess I wasn't very concentrated. Marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that it's been solved but I already had written this up so I figured I'd post it as a visual example.

You'll need to create a Response class to treat the different types of request responses.

For your login you could have something like

```
public class LoginResponse {
    public Boolean success;
    public String message;
    public User user;
}
```

In the case where `success` is true the User object would be assigned but in the event where the `success` is false the message would be set and the user object would be null.

Your login rest interface would then become something like

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/login")
void login(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password, Callback<LoginResponse> callback);
```

You would then be still capable of using your model User object as is without changing it.  You can also create more *Response classes as necessary for your different rest interfaces.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I'll marked your answer as the solved one to help other users that may see this.